# TypeError when feeding Tensorflow dataset with dictionary type

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am not very sure if this is a Tensorflow problem or a python problem. I am very new to both.

My code is based on the wide_deep.py example Tensorflow tutorial provided. I modified the input_fn function so it can take in my dataset ([Train_data.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKST3.png))

Here is the code:

```
def input_fn(data_file, num_epochs, shuffle, batch_size):
  """Generate an input function for the Estimator."""
  assert tf.gfile.Exists(data_file), (
      '%s not found. Please make sure you have run data_download.py and '
      'set the --data_dir argument to the correct path.' % data_file)

  features_interim = pd.read_csv(data_file, usecols=['vgs', 'vbs', 'vds', 'current'])
  labels_interim = pd.read_csv(data_file, usecols=['plo_tox', 'plo_dxl', 'plo_dxw', 'parl1', 'parl2', 'random_fn'])
  features_numpy = features_interim.as_matrix().transpose()
  features = dict(zip(_CSV_FEATURE_COLUMNS, features_numpy))
  labels_numpy = labels_interim.as_matrix().transpose()
  labels = dict(zip(_CSV_LABEL_COLUMNS, labels_numpy))
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))

  if shuffle:
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=_NUM_EXAMPLES['train'])    

  dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

  return dataset
```

But when I execute the code, it has this error:
[image: Error_1]
[image]

The main function of this code is here :

```
def main(unused_argv):
  # Clean up the model directory if present
  shutil.rmtree(FLAGS.model_dir, ignore_errors=True)
  model = build_estimator(FLAGS.model_dir, FLAGS.model_type)

  train_file = "Tensorflow_training_data.csv"
  test_file = "Tensorflow_testing_data.csv"

  train_hooks = hooks_helper.get_train_hooks(
      FLAGS.hooks, batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
      tensors_to_log={'average_loss': 'head/truediv',
                      'loss': 'head/weighted_loss/Sum'})

  # Train and evaluate the model every `FLAGS.epochs_between_evals` epochs.
  for n in range(FLAGS.train_epochs // FLAGS.epochs_between_evals):
    model.train(
        input_fn=lambda: input_fn(train_file, FLAGS.epochs_between_evals, True,
                              FLAGS.batch_size),
        hooks=train_hooks)

    results = model.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(
        test_file, 1, False, FLAGS.batch_size))

    # Display evaluation metrics
    print('Results at epoch', (n + 1) * FLAGS.epochs_between_evals)
    print('-' * 60)

    for key in sorted(results):
      print('%s: %s' % (key, results[key]))
```

In the original example (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/wide_deep/wide_deep.py), the datatype that passed into the model (DNNLinearCombinedClassifier) is a dictionary. I think I am doing the same thing as well, just that I am using DNNLinearCombinedRegressor. But obviously I am doing something wrong.

Can anyone tell me where I messed up? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace? I think if you try to use tf's csv parser, like the wide and deep example does, you won't get this error, since it seems to come from the Dataset.from_tensor_slices call.

Comment: @AlexandrePassos Actually there are two errors but I think they are coming from the same source as you said, Dataset.from_tensor_slices. I updated the error message in the post since I don't know how to put them in comment. Thanks for taking the time looking at them

Comment: I think the problem is that we cannot feed the models (DNNLinearCombinedRegressor) with labels that have data types other than binary or string...

Comment: The problem seems to be that tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels)) expects features to be something we can call tf.convert_to_tensor on to make tensors but it is not.